# Can I use reference image for 3d modeling just from google or is it not legal?

Tags: modeling

I know this is a pretty silly question but I really got no clue if I can use reference images for 3d modeling from google or is it count copyright violation.
thanks for the answerers :)

Comment: I don't think there's any problem but could you tell what kind of object you want to model and for what usage?

Comment: staff for shooter game which I want to publish eventually things such as : weapons, vests, cars.

Comment: are you talking about real cars? I don't think a car manufacturer could claim a copyright if you use one of its models in your game. But if it's a fictitious car that you've found in another game, I guess there's a problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about licensing and legal issues we are neither equipped nor legally authorized to answer, and any ill advice could unintentionally pose a liability to both the user and the network. For official info see the [Blender Licensing Terms and Conditions](https://www.blender.org/about/license/) and the [FAQ about GNU GPL](https://www.blender.org/support/faq/#gnu-gpl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are modelling a specific real-world item, such as a Lamborghini Huracán or .357 Smith & Wesson Magnum, you need to contact the company that owns the intellectual property (IP) or research their policies online. Typically these models fall under a Editorial License (see [**this example**](https://blog.turbosquid.com/turbosquid-3d-model-license/#Editorial-Usage) on Turbosquid), which means you can **NOT** use the model commercially (like in a game or movie) unless you have obtained permission from the rights holder.

Personally, I have a hard time with any non-original 3D model that is being sold on a marketplace even for Editorial Use, unless the creator of the model directly obtained permission from the IP holder.

Here is additional info on [**different model licenses on Turbosquid**](https://support.turbosquid.com/hc/en-us/articles/230097087-Associated-Brands-Information).

Your safest bet, if you plan on creating a model for selling or for use in a game, is to **only use pictures of existing designs as inspiration**, but create a model that is **fully original and unique**, so it does not infringe upon anyone else's copyright.

As a tip, a lot of items that would be used in a game can already be purchased online (for example in the Unity Asset Store or the Unreal Engine Marketplace). Epic Games also has a bunch of free content that they give away each month. You will save a lot of time using pre-made items unless you really need something specific that doesn't already exist. Just make sure the items you use are generic and not "branded" items, as discussed above. :-)

Comment: okey thanks but if I understand correctly if I want to model an M4 the gun or an AK I can't use it in my game? because its a realy world item?

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert in legal matters, you should check online for more info. However, I know companies like AM General tried suing Activision for using the Humvee in their Call of Duty game without permission. However, a judge actually ruled in Activision's favor, citing that they were using the Humvee's likeness for the purpose of  making a realistic depiction of warfare. But it's always safest to ask for permission! However, there's almost no need to model a real M4 or AK as there are plenty of great firearm models online already, including in the Unreal Marketplace. :-)

Comment: FWIW, there's actually a ton of free REAL-WORLD military vehicles available on the Unreal Engine Marketplace. Again, I don't know the legality of using them in games (other than actual military training simulations) so it's probably best to check: https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/profile/Vigilante?count=100&sortBy=effectiveDate&sortDir=DESC&start=0

Comment: I should also note that those military vehicles are "Licensed for Use Only with Unreal Engine-based Products", so the final game would have to be made with Unreal Engine.